# change the webpage according to the screen size

Tags: html, web, tags, screen, paragraph

I am designing a website, i want my website to open all sizes of screens like Desktop various sizes, iphone, ipad etc. I am testing it on safari browser. If i change the browser size, then the data and images inside need to be adjust according to that size. To achieve this, i used Liquid Layout. But i am unable to set the paragraph in percentage. I tried 'em' also. So, i made it 25px. So, here is the issue when i change my browser size, images inside the webpage are changing according to the size that is bigger and smaller but the font size is constant.
How to do this?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using 'em' instead of pixels? Try for example 1.5em instead of 25px.

Comment: I tried 'em' instead of pixels. Even though the information is size is not changing according to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, try `p { word-wrap: break-word; width: 100%; }`.

The magic is `word-wrap: break-word;` What this does is fill the container by height but keep its width.

Also, with this, you don't have to set your `font-size` with `%` but you can use `px`.

http://jsfiddle.net/kQEM8/1/

**EDIT**: Since you revised your question, did you mean something like this? Try running it in jsfiddle and then resize your browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/kQEM8/2/

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    document.getElementById('test').style.fontSize = (document.width * 0.1)+'px'
}
```

Comment: Sorry, even this didn't work, the letters size is not changing when i change the size of browser.